# Adding Values (Dollar Amounts) Together and Prevent Rounding

Tags: javascript, jquery, addition

I need to add values (dollar amounts together) without rounding the values.

Example:

The values being added come from `$("input#lunchorder_item_price")` and output my subTotal.
**2.95 + 2.95 + 2.45 = 8.35** but instead I get **2.95 + 2.95 + 2.45 = 8.36**

Current Code:

```
 function updateCartDisplayTotal() {
     $("div#ordersummary").remove();

     var subTotal = 0;
     $("input#lunchorder_item_price").each(function() {
        subTotal += parseFloat((this.value) + subTotal);
     });

     var orderSubtotal = subTotal.toFixed(2);
     var taxAmount = parseFloat(orderSubtotal*.0685)/*.toFixed(2)*/;
     var deliveryAmount = parseFloat(orderSubtotal*.10)/*.toFixed(2)*/;
     var orderTotal = (parseFloat(orderSubtotal) + parseFloat(taxAmount) + parseFloat(deliveryAmount))/*.toFixed(2)*/;

     var orderSummary = $("<div id=\"ordersummary\"><div>Subtotal: <strong>$"+ orderSubtotal +"</strong></div><div>Tax: <strong>$"+ taxAmount +"</strong></div><div>Delivery Fee: <strong>$"+ deliveryAmount +"</strong></div><div>Total: <strong>$"+ orderTotal +"</strong></div></div>");
     $(orderSummary).insertAfter("ul#cart-items");
  }
```

My question is what do I need to do to prevent these from rounding? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It also depends on the browser, Chrome for example **rounds** toFixed. It is most likely your orderSubtotal that is being rounded up ever so slightly

Comment: I'm using chrome... but is there a way to make sure it behaves as desired across the board, regardless of browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part of the problem is that [floating point arithmetic generally sucks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).  Using floats, your example of...

```
2.95 + 2.95 + 2.45
```

... is actually equal to something like `8.350000000000001`.

The second part of your problem is that browsers have inconsistent implementations of `toFixed()` (some round up, some round down, some round to the nearest significant digit).

Here are some techniques for avoiding these problems:

1. Avoid `toFixed()` if you need cross-browser consistency (which, obviously you do here).
2. Don't do any *intermediate* `round`/`floor`/`ceil`/etc. operations - save that for the very end.  I.e., don't mess with your `subTotal`, `taxAmount`, etc. values except for display purposes.
3. When you need to do a `toFixed()` like operation, there are usually alternative solutions that rely on more accurate and more consistently implemented operations (such as `Math.round()`).  For example, to get a double-precision number, you can do the following:

   `var total = 2.95 + 2.95 + 2.45;`

   `total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;`

---

Here's a refactor of your code making use of the above suggestions:

```
function toDoubleFixed(num) {
    var ret = '' + Math.round(num * 100) / 100;
    return ret.replace(/(\d+)?\.?(\d)?(\d)?/, function(match, l, r1, r2) {
        return (l||'0')+'.'+(r1||'0')+(r2||'0');
    });
}

function updateCartDisplayTotal() {
    $("div#ordersummary").remove();

    var subTotal = 0;
    $("input#lunchorder_item_price").each(function() {
        subTotal += +$(this).val();
    });

    var orderSubtotal = subTotal,
        taxAmount = orderSubtotal * .0685,
        deliveryAmount = orderSubtotal * .1,
        orderTotal = orderSubtotal + taxAmount + deliveryAmount;

    var $orderSummary = $("<div id=\"ordersummary\"><div>Subtotal: <strong>$" + toDoubleFixed(orderSubtotal) +"</strong></div><div>Tax: <strong>$"+ toDoubleFixed(taxAmount) +"</strong></div><div>Delivery Fee: <strong>$"+ toDoubleFixed(deliveryAmount) +"</strong></div><div>Total: <strong>$"+ toDoubleFixed(orderTotal) +"</strong></div></div>");

    $orderSummary.insertAfter("ul#cart-items");
}
```

I wasn't able to test it, so please let me know how it works out.  Also, please note that I modified how you were incrementing your `subTotal` value, as it looked wonky before... but maybe I'm missing something there.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to achieve my goal then?

Comment: Steps 1, 2, and 3 :) 1) Don't used `toFixed()` at all. 2) Don't do any rounding or other operations that lose precision except for when you're displaying the value (never when you're going to use the value again later on). 3) Use my `Math.round()` trick instead of `toFixed()` for display purposes.

Comment: Well I guess that is why I'm asking the question, I don't understand how to achieve that without using. `.toFixed`, `parseFloat` etc... If I remove `parseFloat` all I get is 2.452.952.95 instead of adding the values together.

Comment: That's because you broke steps 1 (avoid `toFixed()`) and 2 (don't do any intermediate operations that cause loss of precision).  When you get a value like `2.452.952.95` that's because you already did a `toFixed()` and are now concatenating strings rather than summing numbers. You're using `toFloat()` to get back to a number, but you're already toast at that point because you have numbers that have already lost precision and are different depending on the browser.

Comment: Also, can you explain the use of `subTotal += parseFloat((this.value) + subTotal);`? Do you really mean to be adding the `subTotal` to your increment value there?

Comment: Using this method you, for a number like 1.23999 you still get rounded up to 1.24 though, is that intentional? @jmar777

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS Hmm.., it was intentional, but maybe that wasn't correct.  Not sure what the desired behavior here is, but it's pretty easy to round up if that's what's wanted.

Comment: @philecker What behavior do you want?  Should each value always be rounded *up* to the nearest cent, or do you want to delay rounding of any type until the final value?

Comment: As far as I can your example solved my issue, I didn't want the subtotal to round, but all other values should round up. Thank you for the input, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @philecker Right now my solution will always round to the *nearest* cent, even if that means rounding down instead of up.  If you want to make sure rounding always happens *up*, you can simply change `Math.round(num * 100) / 100` to `Math.ceil(num * 100) / 100`.

Comment: So basically `.555` would be `.56` and `.554` would be `.55`, correct? If so, that is my desired result.

Comment: Yes, if you want `.555 -> .56` and `.554 -> .55` then the current behavior is correct (using `Math.round()`).

Answer (score 0):

I usually store values like that as penny amounts. Then it's easier to work with.

So $4.95 becomes 495 and $16.32 becomes 1632. Then you can work with full integers and simply add in the decimal point after.

If you can switch to this method I'd recommend it. Otherwise convert the string/floating point value to an integer, do math on it as needed, then return the result.